# Volley NetworkImageView

Tags: android, gridview, android-volley

I have a GridView in which the images are fetched from Network by Volley Library.
And when i click on an item the image opens in full resolution in full screen after downloading, which takes some time.
So i changed it with AppBar but i'm still using the same method to show it, which again takes equal time.

which is :

```
private void fetchFullResolutionImage() {
    String url = selectedPhoto.getPhotoJson();

    // volley's json obj request
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            (String)null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "Image full resolution json: "
                            + response.toString());
            try {
                // Parsing the json response
                JSONObject entry = response
                        .getJSONObject(TAG_ENTRY);

                JSONArray mediacontentArry = entry.getJSONObject(
                        TAG_MEDIA_GROUP).getJSONArray(
                        TAG_MEDIA_CONTENT);

                JSONObject mediaObj = (JSONObject) mediacontentArry
                        .get(0);

                String fullResolutionUrl = mediaObj
                        .getString(TAG_IMG_URL);

                // image full resolution widht and height
                final int width = mediaObj.getInt(TAG_IMG_WIDTH);
                final int height = mediaObj.getInt(TAG_IMG_HEIGHT);

                Log.d(TAG, "Full resolution image. url: "
                        + fullResolutionUrl + ", w: " + width
                        + ", h: " + height);

                ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController
                        .getInstance().getImageLoader();

                // We download image into ImageView instead of
                // NetworkImageView to have callback methods
                // Currently NetworkImageView doesn't have callback
                // methods

                imageLoader.get(fullResolutionUrl,
                        new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(
                                    VolleyError arg0) {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        getString(R.string.msg_wall_fetch_error),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(
                                    ImageLoader.ImageContainer response,
                                    boolean arg1) {
                                if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                                    // load bitmap into imageview
                                    backdrop
                                            .setImageBitmap(response
                                                    .getBitmap());
                                    }
                            }
                        });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        getString(R.string.msg_unknown_error),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            // unable to fetch wallpapers
            // either google username is wrong or
            // devices doesn't have internet connection
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.msg_wall_fetch_error),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    // Remove the url from cache
    AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(url);

    // Disable the cache for this url, so that it always fetches updated
    // json
    jsonObjReq.setShouldCache(false);

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
}
```

So what i'm thinking may be somehow i could show the Image on Next activity which is in AppBar will be the same Network Image(thumbnail) which is already loaded in the grid View so it could be fast.

Thus, what i'm asking is to show the same image which is selected from the gridView in the NetworkImageView of next Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do caching of the images to reuse them. Please go through [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache)
Jake has given a beautiful solution to caching in the link. Hope it helps.